# SciLab is giving "submatrix is incorrectly defined" error

Tags: scilab

I am trying to define vector C like this:

```
[0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02]
```

and then create matrix C_tmp like:

```
[0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02],
[0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02],
[0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02],
[0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02]
```

but I get "Submatrix incorrectly defined" error during last line execution.

```
C = zeros(1, X_SIZE);
C_tmp = zeros(T_SIZE, X_SIZE)
C(1:KSI) = 0.67;
C(KSI+1:$) = 0.02;
C_tmp(1:$) = C;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an mxNc matrix R, where each row of it are de components of the vector C.

1) create a diagonal matrix with C

```
 d = diag (c) (NcxNc matrix)
```

2) create the matrix of ones mxNc

```
o = ones (m, Nc) (mxNc matrix)
```

3) create the matrix 
          R = o*d (mxNc matrix)

Answer (score 1):

If you care for speed, avoid calling `repmat` and use the Kronecker product `.*.`

`C_tmp = ones(T_SIZE, 1) .*. C;`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found solution - repmat function  do this job.

```
C_tmp = repmat(C, T_SIZE, 1);
```